# How to emit light from base color of a wave texture node?

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural

[image: like this wave texture, I want only the red color to emit light]

So as you can see I am trying to recreate the added picture using wave texture node and I want only the red color to emit light. So that to do? and what should be the node set up?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the red part to emit light, use the black and white component from your Wave Texture as the Mix Factor Between a red Emission Shader and whatever you want the rest to be (I left it as a default principled BSDF with a black BaseColor, but you can use whatever you want.)

[image: EmitLight]